# Upgrade 2009 iMac airport card?

Tags: imac

I am having performance issues with my 2009 20" iMac. The wifi signal is not what it used to be, meaning the signal never dropped or loaded blank pages. Have tried Google Chrome and Firefox but both exhibit slow loading pages. I
was wondering if anyone knew of an upgrade for the airport card?

Comment: "The wifi signal is not what it used to be, " How did you make this conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

The airport card is usually pretty stable.  You may want to start with the wireless router / air port.  You can pick one up at your local store and return it if it does not fix the problem.  As for the card itself it's replaceable but not really upgradeable from a quick google search.  If you have a free USB port you can use a Wireless AC USB adaptor like this... [https://www.amazon.com/Edimax-Adapter-Supports-MU-MIMO-EW-7822ULC/dp/B01MY7PL10?tag=macworld05-20&ascsubtag=US-002-3187363-001-1437949-web-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MY7PL10)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do some testing before assuming it's the wifi connection.  As a test, cable connect your computer to your router.  Run speedof.me to check your performance with the cable connected and with wifi.

check how you are connected to your router.

[image]

If needed, change the order:

[image]